# Applications of uniformly convex and uniformly smooth of Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am studying on geometry of Banach space, I want know applications of uniformly convex and uniformly smooth of Banach space in some branches of mathematics and engineering. Can you help me
Thanks your help.

Comment: The same question asked at MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/171562/applications-of-uniformly-convex-and-uniformly-smooth-of-banach-space